# Has anyone tried using a 110v surge protector with a 220v step up transformer? Is its safe?

Tags: electrical-goods

Is it safe to plug in a US (110v) surge protector in Europe to 220v outlet using a transformer - say 2000w? Basically to run a home entertainment center.

Comment: This might better belong on the Electrical Engineering exchange. :-) You can do it. But it's a complex setup just to run gear that you can acquire locally with no awkward transformers and outlet converters. They sell surge protectors there as well (I reccommend you get one).